# Hive "insert into ... select ... limit" very slow

Tags: performance, insert, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on Hive with Spark as the execution engine. Tables are parquet uncompressed.

This statement returns data in a few seconds:

```
select * from mydb.src_table 
limit 100;
```

But when I do the following, the `insert` statement is extremely slow:

```
create table mydb.dest_table
    like mydb.src_table
;

insert into mydb.dest_table
    select * from mydb.src_table 
    limit 100
;
```

I killed the `insert` query after 10 minutes. `src_table` is pretty big (2+ billion rows, several columns containing a lot of text), but I'm only getting 100 rows. I just don't understand how the `select ... limit` is so fast but the `insert ... select ... limit` is so slow.

The `EXPLAIN` for the `select` shows 1 stage. But for the `insert` it shows no less than 8 stages - what's going on?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create table and then insert the records, try **CTAS**
try this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.dest_table 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '28'
STORED AS TEXTFILE AS
 SELECT * FROM mydb.src_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that idiom but I want to know why inserting the data is so slow when I'm limiting the select to only 100 rows.

Comment: Are you executing query on hive console or any other platform?

Comment: Using the Hue web interface.